# Не могу установить модуль "pyttsx3"

Tags: python, windows, pyttsx3

Все перепробовал, но не хочет находить библиотеку.
Уже и сносил pywin32, pypiwin32, pyttsx3 и менял но все равно пишет:

```
>>> import pyttsx3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyttsx3'
```

Comment: Сейчас я скину код ниже что получилось

Comment: C:\Users\Fizer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts>pip3 install pyttsx3
Collecting pyttsx3
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b7/c3/7317dafc544a4de539f729dd494410f7e095fb72db85ef16269f5e7403f7/pyttsx3-2.81-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: comtypes; "win32" in sys_platform in c:\users\fizer\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from pyttsx3)
Installing collected packages: pyttsx3
Successfully installed pyttsx3-2.81

Comment: C:\Users\Fizer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts>python
Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 23:09:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyttsx3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyttsx3'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно у тебя просто не установлены pywin32 и pypiwin32
попробуй эту команду
`pip install pywin32 pypiwin32 pyttsx3`

ну после твоего комента могу предложить снова удалить их всех, потом переустановить, а потом на всякий случай, если ранее написанное не сработает установить библиотеку `speech`
`pip install speech`

Comment: C:\Users\Fizer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python>pip install pywin32 pypiwin32 pyttsx3
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32 in c:\users\fizer\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: pypiwin32 in c:\users\fizer\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: pyttsx3 in c:\users\fizer\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: comtypes; "win32" in sys_platform in c:\users\fizer\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from pyttsx3)

Comment: Уже и сносил по 30 раз, но не помагает

Comment: ну установи `speech`

Comment: мне помогло, но сначала всё ровно удали и переустанови

Comment: Установил я speech, оно не помогло
И сносил только что - не помогло

Comment: тут наши полномочия всё...